# ¿ Cómo poner transparente una escena en Unity mostrando 2 a la vez?

Tags: unity3d

Tengo un juego que cuando pierde va a otra pantalla, pero me gustaría que el fondo de esta última fuera transparente para que se viera también el juego, así como sucede en el juego STACK. He intentado ponerlas solapadas pero no me sale.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir un ejemplo de qué utilizas exactamente para cambiar de escenas? Si lo haces con SceneManager es relativamente sencillo

Answer (score 3):

La clase **SceneManager** tiene el siguiente método:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene ("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

Si por defecto solo le pasásemos el nombre de la escena la cargaría en modo Single, es decir, cierra la escena actual y carga la nueva, Pero si indicamos que el modo será **LoadSceneMode.Additive** , nos la cargará superpuesta a la actual. [Fuente](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)

Después, para que el fondo sea transparente podrías crear uno personalizado con alguna herramienta como photoshop, en las propiedades de la capa le bajas la transparencia al porcentaje que quieras y lo exportas como png, unity respetará esa transparencia.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Sí,uso SceneManager, pero si pongo esa instruccion que me dices ( que ya la usaba) no crea el efecto que quiero. Lo que yo quiero es como el juego **Stack** que tiene 1 botón de "play" y detrás está el juego y al darle al "Play" se quita el boton y empiezas a jugar, y el fondo ni se ha movido ni nada, descargatela y veras exactamente lo que digo Heichi.

Comment: Por cierto, lo estoy probando , como puedo elegir la que va en "additive" ? Yo quiero que por ejemplo ``Scene1`` esté detrás de ``Scene2`` qué pongo?  ``SceneManager.LoadScene ("Scene1", LoadSceneMode.Additive);`` **y cómo sé que la ``Scene2`` va delante?

Comment: @RfMvs Si te vas a file > build settings , ahí imagino que tendrás añadidas tus escenas, verás que a la derecha del nombre en cada una aparece su id. Con esto puedes acceder desde tu script a la escena actual y decirle que cargue la siguiente cuyo id sea el de la actual mas 1 ¿Como se hace esto?, sencillo, `SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);` Así te aseguras que la siguiente escena que se cargue vaya en el orden que tu le hayas dado desde build settings.

Comment: En el ejempo que has puesto en tu comentario cargaría la escena 1 en additive, es decir, la cargaría encima de la escena en la que te encuentres en el momento en que la orden se ejecuta.

Comment: Vale, voy a hacerlo más tarde que ahora no puedo y te comento e intentamos cerrar esta pregunta muchas gracias Heichi.

Comment: @Heichi puedes abrir chat y te comento?Lo prefiero así ahorramos mucho tiempo, pues tengo 1 pantalla principal y 4 pantallas que son el juego. Y cada vez, mediante 1 número random, **cargo una pantalla diferente** y necesito que sea transparente a todas. Abre chat, que yo no sé, y te comento o nos damos cualquier cosa para solucionar esto, espero respuesta!